# How to display multiple Panels one by one in Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms

I am trying to display multiple panels one after another in one single Window using WinForms.
But I am not able to display the panels in order on page load event.

[image: my example]

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fun();
    }
    void fun()
    {
        lst.Add(Panel1);
        lst.Add(Panel2);
        lst.Add(Panel3);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to display the panels in order? tabstop-wize? z-order wise? What is lst object?

Comment: Make them invisible at design time. Then make them visible at run-time by delay. For example you can use `await Task.Delay(2000)` between making them visible.

Comment: Can you give some more details on the desired outcome? Do you need to show those panels each one after a delay or just to show them in the order defined by their position in a List (which would be weird, if no other conditions are in place; i.e. relative positioning, dpi/font scaling...)?

Comment: Form.Controls is a COllection that contains all added controls. You may add your panels in there. Panel.Parent is the control that currently hosts the Panel, so setting it to null removes the Panel from a Form. If all Panels are added to the form, the draw order is the inverse ordner of adding the Panels to the Forms ControlCollection. I'd recommend to remove invisible/unused Panels and only add the one you want to show.